# Print exact location of caught exception in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When throwing exceptions, node.js gives a very helpful precise location using the `^` symbol. I would like to know if it's possible to output the same after catching the exception.

For example, the output of running:

```
var str = '{"regex" : "[\\S]+IS"}';
JSON.parse(str);
```

Gives:

```
undefined:1
{"regex" : "[\S]+IS"}
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bcho/tmp/exception_test.js:2:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

With `^` pointing to the exact location of token S. (This helps differentiate it from other `S` located in the code.)

However, when I run:

```
var str = '{"regex" : "[\\S]+IS"}';
try {
    JSON.parse(str);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

Neither stack nor message contain that location information:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bcho/tmp/exception_test_catch.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
Unexpected token S
```

Can I get the location information from the Exception after it has been caught?

Comment: Note `exception_test_catch.js:3:10` in stack trace.  **3:10** represent line number and column number respectively.

Comment: @EugeneKostrikov yes, that's correct. That points to where `JSON.parse` is called, but not the actual token `S` that caused the parse to fail.